# How can I simplfy the result of Eigenvalues?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, polynomials, number-representation

As we know, the eigen vectors and eigen values of a real symmetric matrix always is are real numbers. I am trying to use the *Mathematica* to verify this theory. Suppose I have a matrix `A`

```
A={{6585, 7579, 6717}, {7579, 11002, 12324}, {6717, 12324, 17030}}
Eigenvalues[A]
```

> `{Root[-13826467396+117514474 #1-34617 #1^2+#1^3&,3],Root[-13826467396+117514474 #1-34617 #1^2+#1^3&,2],Root[-13826467396+117514474 #1-34617 #1^2+#1^3&,1]}`

But I really don't like those `Root`, so I try to simplfy it to a radical expression.

```
Simplify /@ ToRadicals /@ Eigenvalues[A]
```

> [image]

The result includes `I`. Since they are real numbers, could we express this number by radical express without `I`?

Comment: The short answer is no. See [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

Answer (score 1):

As Carl Woll already said in comments, it is in general not possible to express the result in terms of radicals. However one can get a real result in terms of trigonometric functions.

You can use `ComplexExpand` to get a manifestly real expression:

```
 ComplexExpand[ToRadicals /@ Eigenvalues[A]]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot generally express roots of a polynomial of degree higher than two using radicals without using `I`. However, `Root` objects in *Mathematica* are numbers (they just can't be expressed rationally). In particular, for your problem:

```
Im[Eigenvalues[A]]
(* {0, 0, 0} *)
```